# Are not all npm packages available to install with jspm? How do I install them?

Tags: jspm

I'd like to use this npm package in my project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3.promise), but when I search

`jspm install npm:d3.promise --save`

I get back:

`err  Repo jspm:--save not found. Perhaps try jspm install npm:--save.`

I don't understand why jspm can't find it when it's a perfectly valid npm package.  How would I go about installing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use --save, it's not npm, simply try:
**jspm install npm:d3.promise**

Comment: [Smacks forehead].  Thank you!